# Problem with using a text file to create a dictionary that has word length as its key and the actual word itself as the value in Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I'm currently a beginner in Python taking an introductory course for Python and I'm having trouble with creating a hangman game in which we derive our words from a text file that has each word printed on a new line, where we then in a function choose a word at random based on the word length indicated by the user. I'm not sure how we are supposed to do that, I've uploaded my current code, the problem is when I print out the dictionary only the words from the text file actually get printed out, I'm not sure why the dictionary with the keys and values aren't getting printed out... I'm also not sure why my professor wants us to use a try and except in this function and how I'm supposed to use max_size.

Here's what I've currently done

```
def import_dictionary (dictionary_file):
    dictionary = {}
    max_size = 12
    with open ('dictionary.txt', 'a+') as dictionary:
        dictionary_file = dictionary.read().split()
        for word in dictionary_file:
            dictionary[len(word)] = word
    return dictionary
```

The function I'm using to print out

```
def print_dictionary (dictionary):
    max_size = 12
    with open('dictionary.txt', 'r') as dictionary:
        print(dictionary.read())
```

Comment: Yeah, there are multiple words with the same length in the text file, I thought my for loop would loop through every word, is my current code replacing the value each time it has a specific length? I thought I was adding to the set of values.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
def import_dictionary(dictionary_file):
    dictionary = {}
    max_size = 12
    with open(dictionary_file, 'r') as f:
        words = f.read().split('\n')  # each word is on new line so split on newline: '\n'
        for word in words:
            length = len(word)
            if length > max_size:    # If word too long, ignore it
                continue
            elif dictionary.get(length) is not None:
                dictionary[length].append(word)  # If dict already has entry for word length, append word.
            else:
                dictionary[length] = [word] # Otherwise create entry
    return dictionary
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in my answer :  If you use the `get` syntax, the dict returns `None` if the key is not found, whereas if you use the `[ ]` syntax, it returns a KeyError. In the first case you can use an `if / else` construction, and in the latter you need a `try / except KeyError`.   Anyway, I fixed it - should work now!

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this and for introducing me to new ways I can code in Python. I think I am printing out my dictionary incorrectly as I still don't see the different keys and values so I'll keep trying to mess with that, but this is a great base for my Hangman game :))!

Comment: I think you might be mixing up the 'dictionary' in the generic sense of "a collection of words" (your input word list)  and the 'dictionary' in the python sense : "an object containing key-value pairs".

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random

def read_text_file():
    words = defaultdict(list)
    with open("file.txt","r") as f:
        text_file = f.read()
    text_file = text_file.split("\n")
    for wrd in text_file:
        words[len(wrd)].append(wrd)
    return words

def main():
   user_length = int(input())
   words = read_text_file()
   shuffle_words = random.sample(words[user_length])
   print(shuffle_words[0])
```